# ошибка Undefined property: при парсинге JSON в PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5

в строке     foreach($decoded->data as $data) 
происходит ошибка
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
почему это происходит? с другим файлом всё работает хорошо

```js
<?php
function removeBomUtf8($s){
    if(substr($s,0,3)==chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))){
        return substr($s,3);
    }else{
        return $s;
    }
}
$urll = "https://gis-api.aiesec.org/v2/opportunities/757492.json?access_token=e316ebe109dd84ed16734e5161a2d236d0a7e6daf499941f7c110078e3c75493&&with_translations=false";
$content = file_get_contents($urll);
$clean_content = removeBomUtf8($content);
$decoded = json_decode($clean_content);

echo "<table border = 1>";
foreach($decoded->data as $data)
{
    $title = (string)$data->title;
    $location = (string)$data->location;
    $description = (string)$data->description;


   echo "<tr>";
   echo sprintf(' <td>  %s </td><td>  %s  </td><td>  %s </td>', $title, $location, $description);
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Есть вариант `(array) ($decoded->data)`. Но уверен, что в ответе просто нет свойства `data`

Comment: потому что приходит не массив, а один элемент и у него нет `data`....так  что если там иногда все же бывает массив, то следует делать проверку что именно пришло

Comment: а как данные тогда получить?

Comment: без цикла, это же очевидно, обращаясь напрямую

Comment: $title = (string)$content->title;
echo $title;  не работает

Comment: правильно, откуда ты взял `$content` ? ты же в `$decoded` всё "перекодируешь". Вот с ним и работай, только (в данном случае) не циклом

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$title in 


echo (string)$decoded->title;
echo (string)$decoded->location;
echo (string)$decoded->latest_end_date;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66894/discussion-between-normalars-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
function removeBomUtf8($s){
    if(substr($s,0,3)==chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))){
        return substr($s,3);
    }else{
        return $s;
    }
}
$urll = "https://gis-api.aiesec.org/v2/opportunities/757492.json?access_token=e316ebe109dd84ed16734e5161a2d236d0a7e6daf499941f7c110078e3c75493&&with_translations=false";
$content = file_get_contents($urll);
$clean_content = removeBomUtf8($content);
$decoded = json_decode($clean_content);

if(isset($decoded->data) && is_array($decoded->data)){
    echo "<table border = 1>";
    foreach($decoded->data as $data)
    {
        $title = (string)$data->title;
        $location = (string)$data->location;
        $description = (string)$data->description;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo sprintf(' <td>  %s </td><td>  %s  </td><td>  %s </td>', $title, $location, $description);
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}else{
    $title = (string)$decoded->title;
    $location = (string)$decoded->location;
    $description = (string)$decoded->description;
    echo "<table border = 1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo sprintf(' <td>  %s </td><td>  %s  </td><td>  %s </td>', $title, $location, $description);
    echo "</tr>";
    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

И подумайте над тем, чтобы верстку из php выкинуть, по крайней мере, в таком виде (через echo или в переменных).